# For VLC, is there a way to set up or put info in videos so that certain videos will start with subs on but others will start with subs off?

Tags: vlc-media-player, subtitles

I'm trying to set up videos beforehand so that whenever I play one, some videos will start with subtitles, and other videos will start with subtitles off even though they have subtitle tracks available. I'm on Mac and can edit the info or metadata or whatever to accomplish this. Basically I want to set them all up so that I don't have to worry about doing any of that when I actually want to start watching any video. Thanks!

**Edit:**
To be a little more specific, I want any foreign language video to start with English subtitles on, but there are English-language videos with English (and other language) subtitles, too, and I want to keep the subtitles available, but I don't want them to start with subtitles on.